# Dynamic DirectoryIndex (Regex DirectoryIndex?)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, directoryindex

In Apache, is it possible to have a dynamic/regex DirectoryIndex Directive?

Normal DirectoryIndex would do:

```
server/DIRECTORY1 --> server/DIRECTORY1/index.html
server/DIR1/DIR2  --> server/DIR1/DIR2/index.html
...
etc
```

But how would I accomplish:

```
server/DIRECTORY1 --> server/DIRECTORY1/DIRECTORY1.html
server/DIR1/DIR2  --> server/DIR1/DIR2/DIR2.html
...
etc
```

I want this because I have many index files open in my editor, and it's hard to tell the tabs apart because they're all named index.

- I'd prefer something that'll work site-wide in `httpd.conf`
- I want to keep the with/without trailing-slash detection that `mod_dir` has.
- My attempts using `mod_rewrite` tend to mess up the URI variables at the end :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this code in `httpd.conf` (*mod_rewrite* block)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2/$2\.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2/$2.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this only works for two depths of directories, no? In my original examples I meant a solution that would work for any depth...
`server/DIR1/DIR2/.../DIRN --> server/DIR1/DIR2/../DIRN/DIRN.html`

Comment: It doesn't. I've written a code taking what you said into consideration. First block is the  rule for multi-level folder and second block is for one-level folder

Comment: Oh, I understand now! The `$1` in the first block will include slashes. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Exactly. You're welcome. Let me now if it's working as expected for you